# can i create a jar with maven, and use it as a dependency on the main project?

Tags: maven, jar, wsdl, war

I've got a project with webservices and WSDL's. I've accomplished to correctly create the java sources with the axistools-maven-plugin, and also created a folder for each WSDL found.
The steps i must follow now are:

1- Create a Jar with each folder and put it in the "lib" folder of my project

2- Compile the project with those jars and create a war

How can i do that? Can i do all on a single POM? or i need to create a POM for each WSDL and include them in a parent POM?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just deploy you create jar which contains the WSDL into your location repository via **mvn 
install** and on the other hand use it as a dependency.

But it's better to use multi-module build like this:

```
  +--- root
        +--- p-wsdl
        +--- p-war
```

Comment: i think is better ordered with multi-module. I'll make it a try. Do you know any examples of that? Thanks again!

Comment: I'm adding this reference for people who wants to make a multiModule project:
http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html